# How to make the FAQ accordion toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an FAQ accordion and I want it to have two main features:
1- one question and answer can be seen at a time (I managed to do that)
2- if toggling on the open question it closes, and vice-versa (that's what i'm struggling with)

Here's a pen that has a small copy of what I've done on codepen:
https://codepen.io/simokitkat/pen/yLEONpo?editors=0010

here is the html:

```
<div class="text">
        <h1>FAQ</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="question">
              <h2>How many team members can I invite?</h2>
            </div>
            <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the
              Premium
              plan.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="question">
              <h2>What is the maximum file upload size?</h2>
            </div>
            <p>No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="question">
              <h2>How do I reset my password?</h2>
            </div>
            <p>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A
              reset link
              will be
              emailed to you.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="question">
              <h2>Can I cancel my subscription?</h2>                          
            </div>
            <p>Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="question">
              <h2>Do you provide additional support?</h2>
            </div>
            <p>Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

here's the CSS

```
.text h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.question {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

ul li img {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

ul li h2:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
}


li p {
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.active p {
    height: 40px;
}
```

and that's the JS code:

```
let allquestions = document.querySelectorAll("li");

allquestions.forEach(function (question) {
  question.addEventListener("click", function () {
    allquestions.forEach(function (element) {
      element.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use html [`details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#examples) tag

```js
const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

details.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    details.forEach((detail) => {
      if (detail !== el) {
        detail.removeAttribute("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>How many team members can I invite?</summary>
  <p>
    You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
  </p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>How many team members can I invite?</summary>
  <p>
    You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to change the <div> to <details> and the <h2> to <summary> like in your example, but it doesn't toggle still unfortunately.
I think the problem can be fixed in JS, but that's what I can't figure out..

Comment: You need to change `li` to `details`, remove div, and change `h2` to `summary`

Comment: I did as you said and now the toggle problem is fixed but that created another problem, I also wanted that one question and answer can be seen at a time, that seems to have stopped after doing this change

Comment: I must say that I really appreciate you trying to help!
but the issue is still there, the questions toggle but it's allowed to open more than one question at a time.

Comment: I try the stack snipet, when I open first faq the second closes

Comment: I can see that it's now working! I only noticed your html code at first , but now I see your Js and it did the trick indeed. thank you very much!
If you don't mind me asking, I'm a begginer at JS, so I don't know why the name of the attribute 'open' in your code, or what it does exactly, and you didn't mention anything in css, so it seems that your code works automatically. Can you kindly clarify that for me?

Comment: details have open attribute. If you set the attribute to `false` it will close the description and if you set it to `true` it will open it. browser automatically set it open when clicked. remove it same with set it to false.

Comment: Thanks very much once again!